# Linking issues with AWS SDK

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, linker-errors

I have limited knowledge in AWS SDK and Linux, but I have been reading into GCC and CMake syntax and trying to get myself to compile and run the sample on AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html#sample-cplusplus-sdk. Here is my second attempt at tackling this problem.

This is the environment I am running:

- AWS Linux Cloud 9
- gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
- GNU Make 3.82
- cmake3 version 3.6.1

I have used the following commands:

```
- sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel openssl-devel libuuid-devel cmake3
 - git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
 - mkdir sdk_build
 - cd sdk_build
 - cmake3 ../aws-sdk-cpp -DBUILD_ONLY="s3"
 - sudo make
 - sudo make install
```

Building and run of AWS SDK Code:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html#sample-cplusplus-sdk-code
```

My CMakeLists.txt that I use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(s3-demo)
find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)
add_definitions(-DUSE_IMPORT_EXPORT)
add_executable(s3-demo s3-demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(s3-demo aws-cpp-sdk-s3)
```

My modules/directories:

```
environment
- .c9
- aws-sdk-cpp #This is the git source DIR
- sdk_build #This is the build DIR
- CMakeLists.txt (see above)
- hello.cpp
- hello.cpp.o
```

**The Issue:**

Many undefined references, here is a snippet:

- Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration::ClientConfiguration()
- Aws::InitAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const&)
- Aws::S3::S3Client::S3Client(Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration const&, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy, bool, Aws::S3::US_EAST_1_REGIONAL_ENDPOINT_OPTION)
- undefined reference to `Aws::S3::S3Client::~S3Client()
- Some linking issues with Aws::Client::AWSClient::AWSClient(Aws::Client::AWSClient const&)

What I want to know:

1. I know that -L helps to identify the shared library folder that I want to use, and -l the shared file I want to use. However, I have read that when building the AWS project above per instructions on the website, the targets and flags should auto-populate and I should not need to do any special linking to get this project working.
2. It looks like the aws-cpp-sdk-core and aws-cpp-sdk-s3 are in my source folder aws-sdk-cpp. Should this be in my build folder sdk_build? Did I compile my project correctly?
3. How do I build a successful out of source folder aws-sdk-cpp and should I build an in-source folder within aws-sdk-cpp?

Any assistance with my problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues and corresponding solutions to them I have found during my build:

### 1. Undefined linker issues and unable to find dependencies from sdk_build.

**Solution**: Use AWSSDK in find_package of the CMakeLists.txt to guide us

```
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)
```

### 2. Cmake build errors stating Cmake cannot find aws-sdk-cpp files such as aws-sdk-cpp-config.cmake, aws-c-event-stream-config.cmake.

**Solution**: AWS SDK looks for the binary and includes folders from the install path of sdk_build as per [AWSSDKConfig.cmake](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/cmake/AWSSDKConfig.cmake). We shall add into ~/environment/CMakeLists.txt the following

```
set(AWSSDK_ROOT_DIR, "/usr/local/")
```

### 3. Cmake build states that it is looking for static libraries when shared libs have been built during the install of sdk_build.

**Solution**: The CMakeLists.txt from aws-sdk-cpp builds into sdk_build as shared libs, looks like shared libs flag has not been turned on during linking, therefore it looks for static libs, we need to turn this on

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```

---

### Environment

```
AWS Linux Cloud 9
gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
GNU Make 3.82
cmake3 version 3.6.1
```

## Commands that I used to build [C++ Sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html#sample-cplusplus-sdk.):

Install required Tools

```
sudo yum -y install gcc72 gcc72-c++
sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel openssl-devel libuuid-devel cmake3
```

Building project on home/ec2-user/environment/

```
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
cd aws-sdk-cpp
mkdir sdk_build
cd sdk_build
cmake3 .. -DBUILD_ONLY=s3
sudo make install
cd ..
create CMakeLists.txt and s3-demo.cpp here (see below)
cmake3 . 
make
```

### Tested output of executable s3-demo in terminal with

```
./s3-demo my-test-bucket us-west-2
```

---

### Files needed in /home/ec2-user/environment/

**s3-demo.cpp** 
[get your code in this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html#sample-cplusplus-sdk-code)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(s3-demo)
set(AWSSDK_ROOT_DIR, "/usr/local/")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)
add_executable(s3-demo s3-demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(s3-demo ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```